# Pandas format a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is read from a file csv that contains 3 pieces of data **name, class, score**, the dataframe contains duplicates of the name where the value of the score changes, increases or decreases a sort of ranking, my goal is to eliminate all these duplicates and create a dataframe where you only have the name and the total score.

the dataframe look like this:

```
    Class                 Name          Score
0      3CI                Noah          17
1      3FI                Oliver        17
2      3BI                Liam          26
3      3CI                Noah          4
4      3CI                Lucas         34
5      3BI.               Liam          10
```

I want something like:

```
  Class                 Name          Score
0      3CI                Noah          21
1      3FI                Oliver        17
2      3BI                Liam          36
3      3CI                Lucas         34
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: you have an errant `.` in 3BI. in your table as shown.
You can use:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Class', 'Name'], as_index= False)['Score'].sum()
```

gives:

```
  Class    Name  Score
0   3BI    Liam     36
1   3CI   Lucas     34
2   3CI    Noah     21
3   3FI  Oliver     17
```